# Does defining all equivalence classes within a set define an equivalence relation on that set?

Tags: equivalence-relations

I am just starting to learn about equivalence relations and have a question that I think will help solidify my understanding.

Say you want to define an equivalence relation on set $A$.  Is it sufficient to define $S_1, S_2,...,$ and $S_k$ such that $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k S_i = A$ and all $S_i$ are pairwise disjoint, setting each $S_i$ to be an equivalence class?

EDIT: I found a proof that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the equivalence relations on a set $A$ and the partitions of $A$, so the answer to the above question is "yes" -- thank you also to the commenters who pointed this out.

Then, I presume, the equivalence relation $p=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k (S_i \times S_i)$.  Is this correct?

Also, if this is true, then the number of distinct equivalence relations on a set of cardinality $a$ would be $\sum_{i=1}^{a}\frac{a!}{(a-i)!}i^{a-i}$, where $i$ represents the number of equivalence classes (at least 1 and at most $a$). 
 My thinking is that, since you have to put at least 1 element in each group, you can do this in $\frac{a!}{(a-i)!}$ ways.  Then, for the rest of the $a-i$ elements, you have $i$ choices.  But this is not correct... the correct way of counting equivalence relations is described [here](http://oeis.org/A000110) (as pointed out in the comments).  So where did I go wrong in my counting?

EDIT: the above counting method overcounts by distinguishing by order of groups and order of elements within groups.  See the link posted in the comments for the correct solution.

I think the right formula is $\sum_{i=1}^{a}S(a,i)$ where $S$ denotes a Stirling number of the second kind.

Comment: The answer to the question in your 2nd paragraph is "Yes".

Comment: yes, a partition corresponds to an equivalence relation

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A000110

Comment: I don't think your counting formula is correct.

Comment: It seems that you are right.  Why is it wrong, though?  Is there a flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: Try your counting method on sets with a  small number of elements and see where your method goes wrong first. Try it for $2$ elements, then $3$ elements, and so on until you go wrong.

Comment: I see the issue... the ordering within the groups doesn't matter and the ordering of the groups doesn't matter